# render dynamic page using phantom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, phantomjs

I have a dynamic page of which i want to take a screenshot . I am using phantom for it. the website is built on MEAN stack .

Here's the code I am currently using :

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
ph.createPage().then(function (page) {
       page.open("http://localhost:3000/#!/dashboard/somedynamicpageid").then(function (status) {
        page.render('screenshot.png');
        page.close();
        ph.exit();
    });
});
});
```

Now the problem is , i don't get complete screenshot of the page.what i get in screenshot is just some loaded portion of the page.The images and graphs and textual data is still missing .How can i take screenshot when my entire page has loaded (with all the images ,dynamic text , other async stuff).

Comment: what does this have to do with angularjs?

Comment: @Claies:just mention it for the stack used to build website ....

Comment: Maybe `setTimeout(function(){ page.render('screenshot.png'); page.close(); ph.exit(); },5000)`

Comment: [viewportSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html):{width: 1600,height: 9000} // a long page will be downloaded

Comment: Does it register with the onload event of the browser? Maybe you can try something like page.onloadfinished

Comment: Haven't tried it yet .Do you have any example ref.

Comment: @Igor: setTimeout isn't working

Comment: maybe there's a way to wait till the content of a page is loaded? in plain `PhantomJS` setTimeout is working.